# How to remove '/n' from a string in php?

Tags: php

How to remove `/n` from the below `$String`

```
$String = "Local@agent:900/n";
```

I need result like this.

```
$new_string = "Local@agent:900";
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? What issue are you running into writing said regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$new_string = str_replace("/n", "", $String);

Comment: @Rafael Where does Java come from suddenly? If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Comment: String Str = new String("RARA");
System.out.println(Str.replace('R', 'L'));

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
<?php
$str = "Local@agent:900/n";

$str=str_replace("/n","",$str);

echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Local@agent:900/n';

// Using regular expression
preg_replace('/\/n$/', '', $str);

// Straight up string replace
str_replace('/n', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expression use php `str_replace()` funtion.

Find a string `'/n'` and replace with `''(empty)` in `$String` variable

```
<?php

$String = "Local@agent:900/n";
echo $String;
echo '<br>';

$new_string = str_replace('/n', '', $String);
echo $new_string;
```